# Firebase not nesting data under userID - Kotlin // Android Studio // Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm busy creating an app that has swipe features (like Tinder) and I'm stuck on the "Swipe Left" functionality. Specifically adding the data (who swiped left on who) in the appropriate place in the database.

I would like it to look as follows:

- Users
  -UserID (swiped)
  --Name:
  --Email:
  (etc etc)
  --swiped left: ["swiper" uid] - true

edit: The above is not looking like it should... :-/

However, no matter what I try, it ends up nesting the "Swiped left" under Users, not under the specific UserID.
[Here is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbO0D.png)

On a bit of trial and error, I've managed to narrow it down to the fact that it's not picking up the uid child (I hope this makes sense).

Here is the code in question:

```
override fun onLeftCardExit(p0: Any?) {
            var user = p0 as User
            userDatabase.child(user.uid.toString()).child(DATA_SWIPES_LEFT).child(userId).setValue(true)
        }
```

If I change "userDatabase.child(user.uid.toString())" to show "...name.toString()" instead of uid, it also nests it under Users, but it actually shows the "swiped" user's name. just "...uid.toString()" shows ONLY the "swiper's" uid and "true" - here's what I mean:

```
            override fun onLeftCardExit(p0: Any) {
            val swipedLeftUser = p0 as User
            val swipedLeftUserId = swipedLeftUser.name.toString()
            userDatabase.child(swipedLeftUserId).child(DATA_SWIPES_LEFT).child(userId).setValue(true)
        }
```

My question is - how do I nest "swiped left" under the "Swiped" uid, with the "swiper" info? What am I missing?

Let me know if there's any further info needed. The frustration is real.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get the key of the entry because you need to nest it.
I am not an expert of Kotlin but I think you should do something like this:

```
            val key: String = it.key.toString()
            userDatabase.child(swipedLeftUserId).child(DATA_SWIPES_LEFT).child(userId).child(key).setValue(true)
```

Comment: I am so sorry I'm only responding now - I didn't receive notification of your answer! Thank you for this - I will try tonight and update here!

Comment: while the code you posted didn't work, it lead me down a rabbit hole which led me to the solution!! Turns out I missed the fact that when signing up new users, the uid wasnt populating again under the automatically generated uid (yeah I know its duplicating the uid, but I'm a bit of a noob with Kotlin so I'm doing what makes sense to me for now :-) )... this I fixed under the signup fragment, and boom - it nests perfectly! So again, thank you for helping to lead me in the right direction!

Comment: sorry if my code didn't work, but I have never used Kotlin. Anyway, the most important thing is that you have found a solution! ;-)

Comment: please don't apologize! :-) if it wasn't for your suggestion, I would never have found the solution! Somehow it lead me to it and I'm very grateful! :-)